# Trying to code a rock , paper, scissors game in Python

Tags: python, random

When the input is 'r' it works perfectly but when the input is 'p' or 'r' it just adds up these two letters to the word 'scissors´ from the input phrase

```
import random
def play():
   user = input("'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors")
   computer = random.choice(['r','p','s'])

    if user == computer:
        return 'It`s a tie!'

    # r > s, s > p, p > r
    if is_win(user, computer):
        return 'You won!'

    return 'You lost'

def is_win(player, opponent):
    #return true if player wins
    #r>s, s>p, p>r
    if(player == 'r' and opponnent == 's') or (player == 's' and opponnent == 'p') or \
        (player == 'p' and opponnent == 'r'):
        return True
```

Comment: you need to use if, elif, else. As you are using if twice, both parts are going to execute. also in the is_win function you nee to define what happens if something outside if statement occurs. Use if, else

Comment: @user2543622 - No, if the first `if` condition is `True`, the function `return`s and the second `if` is not executed. There is nothing wrong with the `play` function

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `return False` at the end of your `is_win`. You also have a typo (opponnent instead of opponent) in your `is_win` function.

Try the below:

```
def play():
    user = input("'r' for rock, 'p' for paper, 's' for scissors\n")
    computer = random.choice(['r','p','s'])
    
    print(f"You played {user} and the computer played {computer}")
    if user == computer:
        return 'It`s a tie!'
    if is_win(user, computer):
            return 'You won!'
    return 'You lost'

def is_win(player, opponent):
    if (player == 'r' and opponent == 's') or (player == 's' and opponent == 'p') or (player == 'p' and opponent == 'r'):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Could also change `is_win` to be `return (player, opponent) in (('r', 's'), ('s', 'p'), ('p', 'r'))`...

Comment: Indeed, much nicer. Just sticking to OP's code as far as possible to make it easier for them to understand :)

Comment: saves typing and making typos at least :p (probably better setting something like `WIN_CONDITION = ...` and then using that instead of putting it in `is_win`... but yeah...

Comment: Haha, definitely. Could actually just remove the `is_win` function altogether and just use your condition in `play` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but on the `is_win` function you wrote **`opponent`** as `opponnent`:

```py
def is_win(player, opponent):
    if(player == 'r' and opponnent == 's') or (player == 's' and opponnent == 'p') or \
            (player == 'p' and opponnent == 'r'):
```